# Error deploying my Symfony code to App Engine, status: 1

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm currently trying to deploy the Symfony sample [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/symfony) to App Engine Flexible Environment. But I am getting this error.

[image: app.yaml]

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Can you upload the build logs ?

Comment: There is only the build log. This is what is in the second image.

Comment: What if you try to install `google/cloud` package? Seems you missed the `Set up Logging and Error Reporting` from here https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard

Comment: The error message says that some dependencies are missing. You must have missed some of the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks to you for your answers, I solved the problem by installing the `google/cloud-error-reporting` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the feedback I solved the problem by installing the `google/cloud-error-reporting` package

`composer require google/cloud-error-reporting`